# Bmesh.ops.mesh_to_bmesh usage returns cryptic error

Tags: python, bmesh

I was messing around with bmesh and tried to use the mesh_to_bmesh operation, however, I was returned this error...

```
NotImplementedError: mesh_to_bmesh: keyword "mesh" type 4 not working yet!
```

The best I can tell this is saying that the function hasn't actually been implemented into the code and is just a placeholder. If this is correct, can anybody tell me if there is another way to transfer a mesh back into a bmesh object? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `bmesh.from_mesh(mesh)`

Comment: @Chebhou Just did and that did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The proper function to be used is the  `bm.from_mesh(me)` function where **bm** is the bmesh object being transferred to and **me** is the mesh. Also for the reverse operation we can use `bm.to_mesh(me)` which will load the bmesh data back into the mesh.

For code example see the template `bmesh_simple.py` which is included in blender text editor.

---

some of the bmesh operation didn't work yet like `bmesh.ops.bmesh_to_mesh` , `mesh.ops.mesh_to_bmesh` and `bmesh.ops.object_load_bmesh`, the only note is that the [DOC](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_0/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=mesh_to#bmesh.ops.mesh_to_bmesh) says :

> this bmop is private